# Excluding only four-digit and five-digit numbers of a txt file

Tags: bash, shell, vi

I have a file in linux bash, where I have a list of file names basically.

The filenames are including all kind of characters A-Z a-Z . _ and numbers.

Examples:
hello-34.87-world
foo-**34578**-bar
fo.23-**5789**-foobar
and a lot more...

The goal is, that I get a list of only the **four** and **five** digit numbers.

So Outcome should be:
**34578

5789**

I tought it would be a good idea, to work with vi.

So I could use only one command like:

:%s/someregularexpression//g

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you have more than one such number per line?

Comment: No it's only one such number per line maximum. I will try the sed proposed solution below later :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `sed`:

`sed -nr 's/^[^0-9]*([0-9]{4,5}).*/\1/p' < myfile.txt`

Comment: This will return `12345` when input is `foo-123456`.

Comment: Yes, he wanted only 4 or 5 digits. Use `{4,}` in the regex if you want "at least 4" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Without having to store the filenames in a file

```
$ shopt -s extglob nullglob
$ for file in *-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?([0-9])-*; do 
    tmp=${file#*-}             # remove up to the first hyphen
    tmp=${tmp%-*}              # remove the last hyphen and after
    echo $tmp
done
5789
34578
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with 1 instance per line and surrounded by 1 pair of dashes

```
    grep -P '\d{4,5}' mytxt | \
    while read buff
    do
        buff=${buff#*-}
        echo ${buff%-*}
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use vim, and a line doesn't have more than one such number per line, you can try the following:

```
:%s/^.\{-}\(\d\{4,5\}\).\{-}$/\1/g
```

And see `:help \{-` for non-greedy search.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you do not want to parse `ls` in view of spaces, newlines and other special characters. In this case you don't care.
First replace all non-numeric things into newlines.
Than only look for lines with 4 or 5 digits. After the replacement you only have digits, so this can be done by looking for 4 or 5 characters.

```
ls | tr -c '[^0-9]' '\n' | grep -E "^....(|.)$"
```

When you already have the filenames in a file and you are in `vi`, use

```
:% !tr -c '[^0-9]' '\n' | grep -E "^....(|.)$"
```